# How to write out the next 3 or X days with a command?

Tags: date

I can give the day for today in a command:

```
TODAY=`date +%Y.%m.%d.`
```

but how can I give out the next 3 or X days in a command? (Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the man page for the date command and look at the -d option:

```
 % date -d '+1 day'
 Mon Jul 15 21:51:06 PDT 2013
 % date
 Sun Jul 14 21:51:16 PDT 2013
 %
```

I'd also suggest running:

```
 info date
```

for more explicit information.

Comment: For `GNU` date, the info on "1 day" etc, is in the `info` page, and not found in the `man page` on my system.

Comment: however the man page has a small example with --date (aka -d) if you read it.  My specific example is not present.

Comment: BTW, the man page references going to the info page for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `GNU date` available, you can use the following to show today and next 3 days:

```
x=0
while [ $x -lt 4 ]; do
   date -d "$x days" '+%Y.%m.%d.'
   x=$((x+1))
done
```